# Zip multiple database PDF blob files

Tags: php, mysql, database, zip, blob

I have a database table that contains numerous PDF blob files.  I am attempting to combine all of the files into a single ZIP file that I can download and then print.

Please help!

```
<?php 
    include '../config.php';
    include '../connect.php';

    $session = $_GET['session'];

    $query = "SELECT $tbl_uploads.username, $tbl_uploads.description,
                     $tbl_uploads.type, $tbl_uploads.size, $tbl_uploads.content,
                     $tbl_members.session
    FROM $tbl_uploads
    LEFT JOIN $tbl_members
    ON $tbl_uploads.username = $tbl_members.username
    WHERE $tbl_members.session = '$session'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');


    $files = array();
    while(list($username, $description, $type, $size, $content) = 
     mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $files[] = "$username-$description.pdf";
    }

    $zip = new ZipArchive; 
    $zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE); 
    foreach ($files as $file) { 
      $zip->addFile($file); 
    } 
    $zip->close(); 

    header('Content-Type: application/zip'); 
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip'); 
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipfilename)); 
    readfile($zipname); 

    exit();


    ?>
```

Comment: Why doesn't your current code work? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: It creates a zip file that is empty.

Comment: I think it may be a file path/directory issues?  Also, do I need the header information for the blob entries?  
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=$username-$description.pdf");

Comment: hello little bobby - http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PDF data is stored in the database in BLOB fields, I don't see you putting this data in a file. So your ZIP will not contain any files because you don't add real existing files to it.

This is what you are currently doing:

- Reading your data from the database
- Creating an array of filenames
- Creating a ZIP of filenames that might not exist

This what you should do:

- Reading your data from the database
- Creating an array of filenames
- Write your BLOB data into that files
- Creating a ZIP of files that exist

Example:

```
    $files = array();
    while(list($username, $description, $type, $size, $content) = 
     mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $files[] = "$username-$description.pdf";

        // write the BLOB Content to the file
        if ( file_put_contents("$username-$description.pdf", $content) === FALSE ) {
          echo "Could not write PDF File";
        }
    }
```

What you should do if that works for you:

Write the files in a temporary folder (maybe with some help of http://php.net/tempnam) somewhere else and maybe remove them after your archiving process.

There is also a second problem in your code, you use $zipfilename for calculating the content-length and $zipname to read the file and no variable to create the zip. Since $zipfilename and $zipname is not defined, this won't work.

You should define $zipfilename with a ZIP filename and also use that same variable when creating the zip file.

Example:

```
    // a temp filename containing the current unix timestamp
    $zipfilename = 'temp_' . time() . '.zip';

    $zip->open($zipfilename, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($files as $file) { 
       $zip->addFile($file); 
    } 
    $zip->close(); 

    header('Content-Type: application/zip'); 
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=filename.zip'); 
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipfilename)); 
    readfile($zipfilename);
```

Answer (score 0):

[pdftk](http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/) will merge multiple PDF files, as well as [PDFsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/)..